# Jest - Call React Component function without Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I am writing a Test for a React Component `Product`. I am using plain simple Jest without `react-renderer` or `enzyme` and I am aiming to keep it this way for the time being. I need to test a function of a component and havent been able to call it directly through jest. Code given below.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        heading: `Old Heading`
    };

    changeHeading() {
        this.setState({ heading: `New Heading` });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p data-testid='heading'> {this.state.heading} </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

`Jest` Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
// import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Product from './Product';


let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
});

describe(`Testing Product Component`, () => {
    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        // act(() => {
        //     render(<Product />, container);
        // });
        const result = render(<Product />, container);
        const heading = container.querySelector("[data-testid='heading']");
        console.log(heading);
        expect(heading).toBe(`Old Heading`);
        result.changeHeading();
        expect(heading).toBe(`New Heading`);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
});
```

OR

```
   it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const productComponent = <Product />;
        render(productComponent, container);
        const heading = container.querySelector("[data-testid='heading']");
        console.log(heading);
        expect(heading).toBe(`Old Heading`);
        productComponent.changeHeading();
        expect(heading).toBe(`New Heading`);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
```

But it didn't worked. How can I access the `changeHeading` function from the component in my jest test? and call it to change the content of `<p>` tag?

**EDIT**

I will reside with react-test-library if I have to for the timebeing. But it would be great if someone can explain the internal workings as well.

Thank you.

Comment: I see you tagged `react-testing-library` as well. Are you trying to use that instead of enzyme?

Comment: Can't this be achieved without any of these libraries?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to (although I highly recommend using `react-testing-library`)

You should be able to test it in the following way: 

`act(() => {
    render(<Product />, container);
  });
  expect(container.textContent).toBe("Old Heading");`

Comment: Can you please share an example of calling a components function without using `react-testing-library`? Thank you

Comment: I think you approaching this on the wrong way. That function should be triggered by some kind of action or conditional. Currently, it's just sitting there never gets executed. When the header will change? Is it a button click? Then assign it as an event handler. Is it some kind of conditional passed in as a prop? If so, you need to pass down the prop and make sure your state is initialized within the constructor otherwise the prop will be disregarded.

The function then can be called by using the `user-event` library from `testing-library` or `enzyme's` simulate, you have a few options

Comment: If you don't want to use `testing-library` or `enzyme` then you need to find a way to trigger the function, that depends how you implement your class, but I recommend using the above as I said before.

Comment: Can you share an example with react-test-renderer then? The reason you dont see an action event of a button is because this component will be wrapped in a parent component. For this reason I wanted to keep the concise here. You can imagine the click event from a parent component. But in case I want to test this function directly, I am hoping that I should be able to do it directly. Otherwise I wont be able to independently test this component. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To test that, you need a user interaction that calls `changeHeading()`.  In your test, when you do `const result = render(<Product />, container);` you are storing a reference to the component DOM node.

So, you need to modify your component to be able to have an interaction:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        heading: `Old Heading`
    };

    changeHeading() {
        this.setState({ heading: `New Heading` });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p data-testid='heading'> {this.state.heading} </p>
                <button onclick={this.changeHeading}></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

and your test would be:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Product from './Product';


let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
});

describe(`Testing Product Component`, () => {
    it('renders without crashing', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<Product />, container);
        });

        let heading = container.querySelector("[data-testid='heading']");
        expect(heading).toBe(`Old Heading`);

        const button = container.querySelector('button');

        await act(async () => {
            button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
        });

        heading = container.querySelector("[data-testid='heading']");
        expect(heading).toBe(`New Heading`);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
});
```