# test function inside react component without enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I see a lot of solutions saying to use `shallow` from enzyme, however the place I work at said we are not allowed to use enzyme due to having some issues with the pipelines. I've done my best to reproduce the code/problem below...

### The component file

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  btnText: string;
}

function DefaultButton({btnText}: Props): JSX.Element {
  function handleButtonClick() {
    console.log('Default Button Clicked');
  }
  return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>{btnText}</button>;
}

export default DefaultButton;
```

---

### The test file

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import DefaultButton from './DefaultButton';

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== setup tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
// -------------------------------- variables --------------------------------
const btnText = 'Click Me';

// ------------------------------ mock functions -----------------------------
const mockHandleButtonClickFn = jest.fn();

// ---------------------------------- types ----------------------------------
interface TestContainerProps {
  btnText: string;
}

// -------------------------------- containers -------------------------------
function TestContainer({btnText}: TestContainerProps) {
  return <DefaultButton btnText={btnText} />;
}

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== start tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
describe('DefaultButton', () => {
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    const {container} = render(<TestContainer btnText={btnText} />);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('click invokes mockHandleButtonClickFn function', () => {
    render(<TestContainer btnText={btnText} />);
    const btn = screen.getByText(btnText);
    userEvent.click(btn);
    expect(mockHandleButtonClickFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

---

### Execution Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What connection do you think there is between the `mockHandleButtonClickFunction` and the actual implementation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was hoping to get that as an answer. Someway to target the `handleButtonClick()` inside the component...

Comment: You can't. This is nothing to do with React, or Enzyme vs. RTL, just basic JS scope. And more importantly, you _shouldn't_. Test behaviour, not implementation - simulate the click and assert on what the click handler _does_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just found the answer, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding a similar question - [Jest - Call React Component function without Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569426/jest-call-react-component-function-without-enzyme), we can update the two lines in the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import DefaultButton from './DefaultButton';

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== setup tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
// -------------------------------- variables --------------------------------
const btnText = 'Click Me';

// ------------------------------ mock functions -----------------------------
// const mockHandleButtonClickFn = jest.fn(); <--- replace with line below
const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

// ---------------------------------- types ----------------------------------
interface TestContainerProps {
  btnText: string;
}

// -------------------------------- containers -------------------------------
function TestContainer({btnText}: TestContainerProps) {
  return <DefaultButton btnText={btnText} />;
}

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== start tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
describe('DefaultButton', () => {
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    const {container} = render(<TestContainer btnText={btnText} />);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('click invokes mockHandleButtonClickFn function', () => {
    render(<TestContainer btnText={btnText} />);
    const btn = screen.getByText(btnText);
    userEvent.click(btn);
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // <--- update this line
  });
});
```

It looks like by testing what is happening inside the body of the function itself is a way to test the function

[image]